# How to shift variable number of bits to the right from an input register to an output register

Tags: vhdl, state-machine, vivado

I am having an input register which is of 31 bits and I am having an output register which is of 31 bits .Now I have to down scale the data of the input register by a power of 2 say 2^10.So I will write the code as:

output_reg<=input_reg(33 downto 10).

This works fine. Now if I have to change the scaling factor to 2^20, I have to write code as:

output_reg<=input_reg(35 downto 20).
Since I will get different values for scaling factor during runtime, I am assigning the number of bits to be shifted with an index "upper_limit" .If the

```
  upper_limit <=scaling_factor+15;
  output_reg<=input_reg(upper_limit downto scaling_factor);
```

It works fine in simulation but fails during synthesis

Comment: Fails during synthesis how? Provide a [mcve] that produces the error messages or the same error indication. Here you have someone trying to answer a problem that can't be reproduced nor a solution validated by future readers attempting to use your question and any answers as a search resource to solve a similar problem. Without even declarations the problem scope can't be defined.

Comment: In addition to the specific error you’re seeing, some more background would be helpful: what is your application? Is this normalization of data sets of various set ranges to fit sixteen bit values, or are you changing the scaling item by item? What motivates your choice to modify the slice boundaries to achieve power-of-two division rather than use other (simpler) methods? What is this state machine you mention? As @user16145658 points out, without more information, it’s impossible to pin down what the actual VHDL problem is here.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way:

```
process (input_reg, scaling_factor)
begin
    for in in 0 to 15 loop
        output_reg(i) <= input_reg(scaling_factor + i);
    end loop;
end process;
```

Comment: No explanation of the synthesis problem or the why the answer would work? Does it solve the problem and what is the problem? What value is this to future readers? Note the OPs upper limit isn't fixed.